# Нету части свойств в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Хотел изменить задний фон, но нету некоторых свойств. Перерыл интернет в поиске ответа, но ничего нету, буду благодарен за помощь.
[image: Нет свойства background]

Comment: **некоторые** свойства можно добавить **некоторыми** действиями. намёк: добавьте, пожалуйста, конкретики непосредственно в текст вопроса, нажав [edit].